# ngx-build-plus:externals not working for Angular 14

Tags: angular, webpack, ngx-build-plus

Since upgrading my Angular project from Angular12 to Angular 14, I receive following error:

`ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js -o`  or `ng serve` or `ng build` all result in:
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

```
DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.js does not exist.
See "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-LBMvnR\angular-errors.log" for further details.
/ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
```

It then keeps stuck in the `Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...` phase forever. I'm sure that the problem comes from the ngx-build-plus tool, as these errors are quite similar:

https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/314#issuecomment-1089107900
[ngx-build-plus:externals not working for Angular 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929799/ngx-build-plusexternals-not-working-for-angular-13)

The suggested solution from the ngx-build-tool team seems to be to add:

```
window.ng.core = require('@angular/core');
window.ng.common = require('@angular/common');
```

But I don't understand where or how to add this.

My `app.module.ts`file:

```
import {
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  DoBootstrap,
  Injector,
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NoSanitizePipe } from './shared/nosanitize.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent,
    NoSanitizePipe
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [MyComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    if (!customElements.get('my-element')) {
      const webComponent = createCustomElement(MyComponent, {
        injector: this.injector
      });
      customElements.define('my-element', webComponent);
      console.log('registered my component');
    } else {
      console.warn('the my component was already registered');
    }
  }
}
```

`angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-dashboard": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../app/src/main/resources/static/my-widget",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              {
                "bundleName": "polyfill-webcomp-es5",
                "input": "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"
              },
              {
                "bundleName": "polyfill-webcomp",
                "input": "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce-pf.js"
              },
              "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim.js",
              "node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/elements/bundles/elements.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.local.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.local.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.local.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-dashboard:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-dashboard:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-dashboard:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-dashboard:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-dashboard:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-dashboard",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
   {
  "name": "my-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-dev": "ng build -c=dev --single-bundle --output-hashing none && node concat",
    "build-staging": "ng build -c=staging --single-bundle --output-hashing none && node concat",
    "build-prod": "ng build -c=production --single-bundle --output-hashing none && node concat",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "npx eslint src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue,scss,json,css,html} --quiet",
    "format": "npx prettier --write src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,scss,json,scss,css,html}",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:externals": "ng build --extra-webpack-config /webpack.externals.js --prod --single-bundle",
    "postinstall:bak": "",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.0.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer": "^15.13.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.5.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.6.0",
    "contentful": "^9.2.4",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.37.0",
    "concat-files": "^0.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "schematics-scss-migrate": "^1.3.15",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "[module-name]": false
  }
}
```

`webpack.partial.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
    module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          "VERSION": JSON.stringify("4711")
        })
      ]
    }
```

`webpack.externals.js`:

```
 const webpack = require('webpack');

 window.ng.core = require('@angular/core');
 window.ng.common = require('@angular/common');

 module.exports = {
   "externals": {

   }
 }
```

Comment: I found one example but it doesnt contains full solution. But at least it generates UMD files for Angular and RxJS packages which can be later used for generating single file. But still in progress to make it work https://github.com/peterblazejewicz/angular-umd-bundle